# SQL Stored Procedures : Count, Join and group by but it is shown 'NULL'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I got stuck something about stored procedures I write a stored that i need to shot three columns of products count like this

```
SELECT 
    Count([TPDTN].[ProductName]) as 'Product Count',
    [TPDTN].[CategoryID]
FROM 
    [TPDTN]
LEFT JOIN 
    [TPDCN] ON [TPDTN].[CategoryID] = [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]
GROUP BY 
    [TPDTN].[CategoryID], [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]
```

It shows results like this:

```
   Product Count    CategoryID
   ---------------------------
        2               1
        9               2
        2               3
        2               4
        1               5
```

But I don't know how make it show

```
   Product Count    CategoryID       libDocumentID
   -----------------------------------------------
        2               1               123456789
        9               2               123456789
        2               3               123456789
        2               4               123456789
        1               5               123456789
```

Producer ID (`LibdocumentID`) is from other table but when I `SELECT [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]` the value is `NULL`

```
Product Count    CategoryID       libDocumentID
------------------------------------------------
    2               1               NULL
    9               2               NULL
    2               3               NULL
    2               4               NULL
    1               5               NULL
```

How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: because your CategoryID and libDocumentID are different... are you sure [TPDTN].[CategoryID] is equal to [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]?

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the select, and if you don't need the NULL you need an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Count([TPDTN].[ProductName]) as 'Product Count',[TPDTN].[CategoryID], [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]
FROM [TPDTN]
inner join [TPDCN]
ON [TPDTN].[CategoryID] = [TPDCN].[libDocumentID]
GROUP BY [TPDTN].[CategoryID],[TPDCN].[libDocumentID]
```

Comment: So, there is a NULL in that column. Can you share your tables schema and data? Maybe with [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: but in that field have a value :'(

Comment: hey I solved it , just use a ParentID on the same Tables